# I have no app.UseMvc in Startup.cs on a fresh application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have generate a new ASP.net Core MVC 3.1 application with this command:

```
donet new mvc
```

Everything works fine but i want to understand something:

Why does my startup.cs file does not contains this line:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

I have see this line in a tutorial and i want to understand why my application works without this line

Thanks

Edit: Here is what i see in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does it have?

Comment: I do not understand your comment sorry

Comment: Show what is in Startup where you say AddMvc is missing

Comment: See my edit. I think the app.UseEndpoints is doing the job but what Microsoft provide this line instead of useMvc ? Can we say useMvc is deprecated ? Thanks

Comment: `AddControllersWithViews` combined with `UseEndpoints` basically replaces what was done by `UseMvc`

Comment: `UseMvc` is being gradually phased out.

Comment: Check breaking changes in migration notes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code